# No internet connection in Ubuntu-- (windows WSL)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu in ***windows wsl***. But the problem is that I have two separate internet connections. one is Modem (local SIM data connection), and another is a WI-FI bandwidth connection. When I connect my computer to WIFI. The ubuntu network connection was lost. But When I connect Modem again, the wsl connection gets back. What is the problem?

If my question is not understandable, please comment under the question.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you try ensuring that your system is disconnected from cellular and connected to WiFi, then reboot Windows and see if Ubuntu's Internet access now starts working with WiFi? If so, does it then stop working if you switch to cellular?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 I tried this process that you are saying but not working... I have edited `resolve.conf` by following another question but I don't know why these thing is not working. :-(